# Best strategy to handle NULL rows from calculated features of previous dates?

Tags: time-series, python, missing-data, data-imputation, feature-engineering

I have event data that contains the history of a player's performance in tournaments over the last few years. What I want to do is predict the chances of the player winning a new tournament based on the past data.

So, I have calculated a number of features to train the model on the historical data. Lets say for example, given a date, event and player id, these could be:

```
    date          eventid      playerid     past_races    past_wins    last_played
    2015-10-01    123          A            NA            NA           NA
    2015-10-01    123          B            NA            NA           NA
    2015-10-01    123          C            NA            NA           NA
    ...
    ...
    2016-01-15    145          A            10            1            45
    2016-01-15    145          B            7             3            90
    2016-01-15    145          D            NA            NA           NA
    ...
    ...
```

So, if I calculate the number of past races, past wins, days last played etc., the first date a horse races (top 3 rows) will be null since there is no past data in my dataset. But there were actually tournaments before that as well, the data I have just start at that date.

I need to keep these rows because I don't want to lose the data when a horse is first racing. What would be the best strategy to filling these NULLs? Since, they occur at the first race of a horse, I cannot take the mean of the past races of the horse.

Is it a good idea to impute the values using future data? I have real reservations against that. Just wanted to know what the prevailing best practice is in cases like this?